# How can I configure my wireless power switches to default to on after power outage?

Tags: electrical, switch

I currently have ETEKCITY remote power switches.
I need to use two of these for ceiling LED lights that needs to be default on after power cycle.

This video shows someone being able to configure it to be normally on, which is what I want. However he doesnt say how he did it. I(t is seemingly not a hardware mod.
Anyone know how to do this ? I cannot figure it out. 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiCb1L5YXno"

Alternatively, If anyone has wireless power switches that can be configured as "default on" after powercycle, then please post the model.

Comment: Do you have the instructions for your model of switch? It may help.

Comment: It says nothing about it, although the video clearly shows it can be done.

Comment: Two points I note, one is that switch 5 seems to go "off" when he hits the left button - which is labelled "on" and he also uses the switch on the top right of the plug-in unit. So, possibly he took it apart and changed the wires on the relay so he has "normally on" instead of "normally off"... too many possibilities to be sure, but check out the switch top right...

Comment: +1 for manassehkatz - So I pulled up the manufacturers web site took a look and under MANUALS and there are instructions that tell you exactly how to program your device to do what we call a "fail to on" position. Ignore the video it says nothing. Good Luck

Comment: Do you have a smart home hub controller?

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician I couldn't find that but I'm device-impaired right now.  I agree the video is usless and dubious.  He doesn't even pull it long enough for the supply capacitors to discharge.

Comment: I dont know which manual you read but https://static.etekcity.com/files/manual/10-BH9938U-3%20%20Wireless%20Remote%20Control%20Electrical%20Outlet%20manual%20US.pdf shows nothing of the kind. Can you just cut and paste the manual you refer to ?  No I dont have a hub co0ntroller.

Comment: @diyer and others - here is the web site reference https://static.etekcity.com/files/manual/10-BH9938U-O%20Single%20Outlet%20Receiver%20manual%20manual%20US.pdf . You can find the instructions under the "Detailed self-learning operation section. Good luck.

Comment: It is definately not what the manual means to say. I can see that it could be confusing. I have 5 of these and confirmed the following.
It means you can press either of on or off to let the  remote and the socket pair. It does NOT mean that it will be default on if you paired it with the on button or off when you paired it with the off button.That I tried to do with 5 of them I have and they behave as I describe.

Comment: Search google for " ETEKCITY hack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer came  back to me as follows:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to our support team. Unfortunately, there
>   is not a programmable way to do this. The person in the video has
>   modified his outlet to be able to have the light power on as soon as
>   it is plugged into the outlet.
>
> Please feel free to reach out to us if you have any further questions
>   or concerns. We hope you enjoy the rest of your day.

Anyway, it is clear from the manufacturer that the wireless plug cannot do what is in the video.So all the claims from interpreting the manual that it can, is false.

Answer (score 3):

I have no personal experience with ETEKCITY. However, based on a quick, non-scientific, perusal of their web site, I get the sense of "pretty web page selling cheap junk". Not that I am against cheap junk per se - I often go that direction myself, *for certain products*. But for controlling 120V equipment, I tend to prefer the better stuff. The rules are a bit different (for good reason) for devices hardwired to your electrical system, and, partly as a result of the R&D and testing required, they tend to be more long-term feature complete, reliable and *safe*.

I would look at Leviton or Lutron or another manufacturer that **specializes in electrical equipment**, not a catch-all "USB mag-stripe reader, blood pressure monitor, digital scale, back massager, air mattress, etc." company that happens to have some WiFi controlled plugs too. (I have no problem with a retailer (online or bricks 'n mortar) that sells "everything under the sun". But a manufacturer can't possibly *specialize in everything*.)

Then you can check the online manuals and if they don't have enough details you have a reasonable hope of contacting someone who can answer your specific questions.

Comment: I dont agree, but thank you for your opinion.                                                                                                               These are the best power switches I ever bought and I had a lot. The question is either to help resolve what the user in the video achieved, or to suggest a brand/model which can actually work default on based on actual user expereince. So far the Eteckcity seems the only ones that were capable to0 do it I cannot contact the poster of the video or figure out how he configured it without mods.